# how to configure google analytics module in dotnetnuke

Tags: google-analytics, dotnetnuke, configure

How can we configure google analytics module in dotnetnuke
Just I saw this link.
https://support.powerdnn.com/kb/a1780/how-to-configure-google-analytics-module-in-dotnetnuke_.aspx.
But whats this account id mentioned here as Tracking ID that we need to enter ?

-Rigin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It corresponds to your Google Analytics account number. It is something like 'UA-XXXXXX-XX'.

Comment: Stephane,I could found something like :  
ga('create', 'UA-****-**', 'myUrl.com');
in the script. Is it this UA-*****-** ?? the same thing only , I need to update there also ?

Comment: Yes, you only have to enter this "UA-**" in the Google Analytics setting form of DotNetNuke. Be carrefull that Google Analytics stats should show changes only after 24 hours.

Comment: I have updated the script via Admin > settings > Google Analytics
But its not the same as what I pasted there, myUrl.com and all isnot visible, when i take the viewsource 
Is that ok or any defect ?